# ADF - Get list of files from the public HTTP

Tags: azure, http, azure-data-factory

I currently have a solution where I am downloading zip files from a public HTTP. I have a solution to dynamically pass file names, but I'm wondering if there's a solution to get the list of files from the HTTP instead. So instead of passing a specific name, I'd like pull the list of file names, compare to existing files in BLOB, and proceed with downloading new files. Is that feasible to achieve in ADF?

Below are the URL paths:

```
https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_September_2022.zip
https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Deactivated_NPI_Report_091322.zip
https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_090522_091122_Weekly.zip
```

Attempted Solutions:

- tried passing a wildcard in the URL: https://download.gov/data/NPPES_*
- tried get metadata activity, but it does not support HTTP.
- tried web active, but that's for API only.

Thanks!

Comment: The link you have provided is not working. Is it possible for you to provide a valid URL so the issue can be reproduced in order to find if there is a solution?

Comment: Thanks, @SaideepArikontham . I've now updated the URLs to reflect what is current. I was mostly asking if conceptually if this task was possible to achieve, but if it helps to have the valid URLs, they're available now. Thanks!

Comment: The provided URL are still not working (trying to open the url is throwing `page can't be reached`  error).

Comment: @SaideepArikontham Sorry about that. Third time is the charm. I've verified these URL are correct. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @MikeV, I don't think it is possible to get the list of files as per your requirement. Unless the URL you are using returns a response that returns the list of all files, it might not be possible to achieve the ask.